# How to put condition that will check the validity of 30 days or more than 30 days

Tags: php, laravel, date

I have a form with text fields Arrival and departure like:

Arrival : 07/18/2018
Departure: 08/18/2018

If i want to stay for 30 days its says We have 2 nights minimum, please select at least 2 nights stay.

but here i want if i select 30 nights stay it let me save my dates.

[image: this is the image showig details of my task]

My Controller code from where this condition is coming:

```
     // check minimun nights

    if($season!=null) {

        if ($season->minimum_nights != '' && ($number_of_days) < $season->minimum_nights) {

             $response = [
                'status' => 'error',
                'error' => 'Should be  ' . $season->minimum_nights . ' minimum nights in this season.',
            ];

            \Session::flash('error', 'We have ' . $season->minimum_nights . ' nights minimum, please select at least ' . $season->minimum_nights . ' nights stay.');

            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

what i can do here that its let me add 30 or more than 30 nights stay:
Here your help will be highly appreciated!

```
    $from_date = $request->get('arrival');
    $to_date = $request->get('departure');

    $number_of_days = numberOfDays($from_date,  $to_date );

    $status = $property->isPropertyAvailable($from_date, $to_date);
```

Comment: Look into carbon class where you will be able to add/compare days https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: it's normal you have chosen just one night in the given image !!!

Comment: if i add one month it should add but its keep displaying this message

Comment: can you add the code where you get the `$number_of_days` ?

Comment: i add the code please see

Comment: You have to add the `numberOfDays` ;)

Comment: How i can add the numberofDays can you please help me regarding this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176231/discussion-between-maraboc-and-shahzad1122).

Comment: are u there please come on chat @Maraboc

Answer (score 0):

Using [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) to get the number of days, would be a cleaner way of doing this, imo.

```
        $from_date = Carbon::parse($request->get('arrival'));
        $to_date = Carbon::parse($request->get('departure'));

        $number_of_days = $from_date->diffInDays($to_date);

        if ($number_of_days < $season->minimum_nights) {
            $response = [
                'status' => 'error',
                'error' => 'Should be  ' . $season->minimum_nights . ' minimum nights in this season.',
            ];

            \Session::flash('error', 'We have ' . $season->minimum_nights . ' nights minimum, please select at least ' . $season->minimum_nights . ' nights stay.');

            return redirect()->back();
        }

        // Continue logic
```